# Confusion solving constant function

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis

Find $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which is not a constant function which is neither star-concave, nor star-convex, but both concave and convex.

Please help me how to solve for this function?

Comment: What is $R$? the real numbers? What have you tried?

Comment: yes it is real number

Comment: What does it mean for a _function_ to be "star-convex"?

Comment: Sorry it is wrong it should be strict concave, non strict convex

Answer (score 2):

A function that is concave *and* convex, but not strictly, and not constant is the following

$$f(x) = x, \ x\in\Bbb R$$

Comment: can you help more because it is a bit challenging for me

Comment: Then my example works for you!

Comment: ıt is not enough for me

Comment: What does it mean for a function to be convex on the whole $\Bbb R$??